# Looking for a directory in an unknown path

Tags: c#, file, directory

I am working on my application in C# Windows Forms and I can't figure this one thing out. I need to get a file from a directory that path is unknown to me. I feel like I've already tried everything I could find and nothing worked for me, or maybe no one explained it to me properly yet.

[Here's my 10iq fix for that right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZlzO.png)

Right now, I'm checking a couple of optional folders, but that's still not enough since this directory @"C:\Battlestate Games\EFT\EscapeFromTarkov_Data\StreamingAssets\Windows\assets\content"
always has a different path.

Does anyone have any ideas how I can access folder `EscapeFromTarkov_Data\blablabla\blabla` without knowing the path?

Also this is a game directory, not my program's directory or Windows directory. And if you're wondering, my application is working as a file modifier for games, that's why I'm messing with the files of another video game.

Comment: Maybe use [EnumerateDirectories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratedirectories?view=net-7.0#system-io-directory-enumeratedirectories(system-string-system-string-system-io-enumerationoptions)) with `EnumerationOptions.RecurseSubdirectories`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/238704)

Comment: What is your criterion for choosing `esp_directory`. Could you enumerate directories like Stuart suggested until you find one called "head_0_bundle"? Could you just simplify the your current check by putting all of the guesses into an array of strings and returning the first guess that corresponds with an existing directory?

Answer (score 2):

First find the `EscapeFromTarkov_Data` folder from the possible candidates.

I am splitting the parents of it into 2 parts:

- Drive root (like `C:\`)
- Between the root and `EscapeFromTarkov_Data` itself (like `Battlestate Games\EFT`)

```cs
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

private string? GetDataPath()
{
    string[] candidates = {
        @"Battlestate Games\EFT",
        @"Battlestate Games",
        @"Tarkov",
        // add more candidates here
    };

    // Retrieving drive roots, such as @"C:\" and @"D:\"
    IEnumerable<string> roots =
        DriveInfo.GetDrives()
        .Where(d => d.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
        .Select(d => d.Name);

    // Matching every root and candidate, plus "EscapeFromTarkov_Data"
    var paths = 
        from root in roots
        from candidate in candidates
        select Path.Combine(root, candidate, "EscapeFromTarkov_Data");

    // Checking whether each of combination actually exists
    foreach (var path in paths)
    {
        if (Path.Exists(path))
            return path;
    }

    // If none of them exist...
    return null;
}
```

And then, use the previous method to get the path, and `Combine()` the rest of the full path to it.

```cs
// If GetDataPath() is null, the following "is" statement returns false.
// Otherwise, it returns true and the value is stored to dataPath.
if (GetDataPath() is string dataPath)
    string esp_directory = Path.combine(
        dataPath, @"StreamingAssets\Windows\...\bear_head_0.bundle"
    );
else
    Application.Exit();
```